# How to properly implement combodate library

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I’m trying to implement date-picking library [combodate.js](https://vitalets.github.io/combodate/) into a simple react app and as a relative beginner, i’m lost.

The website instructs me to include combodate, moment, and jquery onto my page with

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="js/moment.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/combodate.js"></script>
```

I’ve included these scripts in the header of my index.html, but unsure if this is correct as I do not have a ‘js’ folder anywhere in my app.

It also provides source code for a variety of drop down date selection formats. The one I chose reads:

```
<input type="text" id="datetime24" data-format="DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm" data-template="DD / MM / YYYY HH : mm" name="datetime" value="21-12-2012 20:30">
<script>
$(function(){
$('#datetime24').combodate();
});
</script>
```

which would display the date selection form like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAGeM.png).

So what I’ve done is place the above code inside the return of my render function inside my react component. I’ve imported jquery and moment into that component, but it’s unclear how to import combodate as it doesn’t look like there is any documentation on react compatibility. It appears to just be a rogue js file that installs to the folder path ./bower_components/combodate/src/combodate.js inside my app folder. When I run my app, it gives me an error saying combodate() is not a function.

Overall - I’m unsure how and where I should be linking these library packages I’ve installed and how I should be custom tailoring the combodate code to fit my needs as my gut says it wasn’t written with React in mind.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: `but unsure if this is correct as I do not have a ‘js’ folder anywhere in my app` you need to update the file paths to be relevant to your system

Comment: So i updated the script src to point to my combodate.js file at the bower_component location, but my app still states:

TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...)(...).combodate is not a function.

Does this mean I need to also point my jquery script to the jquery.js file located in my node_modules folder?

Comment: Also - based on my knowledge of react, I need to export something within the comobodate.js file in order to pull it into my component, but the comobodate code doesnt seem to be written that way. Where my code states ```$('#datetime24').combodate();``` seems to be indicating that it should be pulling in ```combodate()``` from somewhere (i'm assuming combodate.js) but it can't because nothing is being exported. The ```$``` is (I'm assuming) jQuery, which I have 0 experience with, but noticed that in order to import it into my component, I had to ```import $ from 'jQuery'```, but maybe I'm wrong?